# What is the parameter I should use to find the exact search term

Tags: google-custom-search, google-apis-explorer

Using google search engine api to extract data from google. what is the parameter I should use to find the exact `search_term`

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="YOUR_KEY"&amp;cx="ENGINE_API"&amp;q="search_term&amp;alt=json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try `exactTerms`.

> `exactTerms` (string) - *Identifies a phrase that all documents in the search results must contain.*

Request > Parameters > exactTerms
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list#exactTerms

Comment: How do I implement multiple phrases that the page needs to include? For example, I want ("This" "is" "a" "test") and not ("This is a test")